# How to get a smooth sine wave alternation with Javascript/JQuery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have run into some trouble trying to get html and jQuery to create a smooth sine wave pulse on the font-size of a div. I have the alternation working but it seems too choppy. Is there a more mathematical approach to optimizing javascript's math.sin() within setTimeout() so that the font-size in terms of px can increase and decrease at a smoother rate?

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var i = 10;
  var fontsize;
  function pulseLoop() {
        fontsize = (Math.sin(i) * 10) + 50;
        $(".changer-container").css("font-size",fontsize + "px");
        i = i + .5;
    setTimeout(pulseLoop, 100);
  }
  pulseLoop();

  $(document).focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MdQxh/2/

Comment: "*optimizing javascript's math.sin()*" - why that? To get a smoother animation, you will need to decrease your timeouts. And why don't you use jQuery's `animate` function?

Comment: Well, right now, you're only running at 10fps. Might you not try bumping that up to something that humans consider to be smoother, first? How about trying something like 32ms instead of 100ms?

Comment: `var mark = new Boolean(true);` - Huh? And what do you need this for?

Comment: I updated the question and removed the junk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust the `timeout` duration.

100 ms is equivalent to **10fps** (calculated by 1000/100).

To appear smooth, you need at least 24-30 fps, so set the delay to at least `40`ms or `30`ms or (even `16`ms for *60fps*) to get a smooth *animation*.

That's why you see the animation as choppy.

Here's your fiddle at 60fps, I changed the `i` increment from `i = i + .5;` to `i = i + .2;` : http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/mecPv/

Comment: very nice! so when you increase the fps and decrease the unit of increment then it becomes smoother.